# How do I write a salt state to pip install requirements file?

Tags: python, yaml, salt-stack

Can't find this written down. I'm trying:

```
pip.install:
  - requirements: /path/to/requirements.txt
```

But I'm getting the error that

```
ID pip.install in SLS python.python-pip is not a dictionary
```

Many of the other ways include virtualenvs, but I don't want to use a virtualenv to do this as it's for a virtual machine, so there's no point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

pip.install**ed**

```
pip.installed:
  - requirements: /path/to/requirements.txt
```